# iOS 6 UITextField inside UITableViewCell with sections get wrong data on scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

So basically I am getting the wrong data on every textField by scrolling my TableView (Everything is mixed up). I know, this is because the awesome optimization of the reusable cells in the UITableView, so the indexpath are changing constantly, but still I don't know how to solve this.

Having an UILabel in the same cell I solved this problem by adding a specific tag in every label view, so the tableview knows which data is going to return on a view but for some reason this is not possible for my textfield view.

Here is my code:

```
#define DESCRIPTION_TAG 10
#define TEXTFIELD_TAG 11
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Description Cell";
// Intatiating  my own TableViewCell
CustomLocationCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (!cell){
    cell = [[CustomLocationCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.rowText = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:DESCRIPTION_TAG]; // returning view with unique tag
cell.rowTextField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:TEXTFIELD_TAG]; // NOT WORKING!!! Data get mix up
cell.rowTextField.delegate = cell; // sending the delegate to custom class cell
cell.delegate = self; // make connection with my @protocol

switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        cell.rowText.text = [self.descriptions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.rowTextField.placeholder = [self.descriptionsPlaceholder objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        break;
    case 1:
        cell.rowText.text = [self.rooms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.rowTextField.placeholder = [self.contentPlaceholder objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
return cell;
```

}

Any help is appreciated.

Here is an update of my data source:
On my CustomTableViewCell I do have outlets for my UILabel and UITextfield

```
// UITableView DataSource

- (NSArray *)sections
{
    if (!_sections){
        _sections = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"First Description", @"Second Descriptions", nil];
    }
    return _sections;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)rooms
{
    if (!_rooms){
        _rooms = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return _rooms;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return self.sections.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return [self.descriptions count];
            break;
        case 1:
            return [self.rooms count];
            break;
        default:
            break;
     }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Setting placeholder you don't change the displayed text.

Comment: Can you try with [cell.contentView viewWithTag:TEXTFIELD_TAG];

Comment: Thanks for the response! 
@A-Live, I think this is not the problem because when the user writes some text and scrolls the table, this new text gets mixed up.

Comment: @Anupdas, I already tried like you said, but I'm getting exactly the same output.

Comment: Your problem doesn't have anything to do with tags. In fact, you don't need tags to do what you're trying if you have outlets to your text field and label in your custom cell. You should post some information about your data structure (is it 4 arrays?) and what you have in numberOfSectionsInTableView: and numberOfRowsInSection:

Comment: Another question. Is this only a problem with the text the user enters? Is the placeholder text working properly?

Comment: @Ramiro Thüringen exactly, it happens because you set the placeholder text but the content text from the reused cell is not changed according to the new indexPath.

Comment: @rdelmar, Thank you for the response, I just updated my code. And answering your questions: No, neither the placeholder nor the text the user enters works.

Comment: It's hard to diagnose what's going on here -- it makes no sense that the label should work properly but not the text field (at least for this placeholder text). Are the number of items in contentPlaceholder and descriptionPlaceholder the same as in descriptions and rooms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but here's an example that works with labels and text fields with placeholder text. You'll notice that in cellForRowAtIndexPath, I set both the text and placeholder to nil, so that when a cell is reused, it doesn't have the wrong text in it. Also, when doing the text fields, I check if the array has placeholder text at that index, and if so, I reset the placeholder, and if not I reset the text.

In order for the text field delegate methods to work properly, each text filed needs a unique tag (not just one tag for labels and another for text fields) that I set equal to (indexPath.row + 1000*indexPath.section).

```
#import "TableController.h"
#import "CustomLocationCell.h"

@interface TableController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *descriptions;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *descriptionsPlaceholder;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *rooms;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *contentPlaceholder;
@end

@implementation TableController 


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.descriptions = @[@"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four",@"Five",@"Six",@"Seven",@"Eight"];
    self.descriptionsPlaceholder = [@[@"Placeholder1",@"Placeholder2",@"Placeholder3",@"Placeholder4",@"Placeholder5",@"Placeholder6",@"Placeholder7",@"Placeholder8"] mutableCopy];
    self.rooms = @[@"Room1", @"Room2", @"Room3", @"Room4",@"Room5", @"Room6", @"Room7", @"Room8"];
    self.contentPlaceholder = [@[@"ContentPH1",@"ContentPH2",@"ContentPH3",@"ContentPH4",@"ContentPH5",@"ContentPH6",@"ContentPH7",@"ContentPH8"] mutableCopy];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.descriptions.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Description Cell";

    CustomLocationCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.rowTextField.delegate = self;
    cell.rowTextField.tag = indexPath.row + 1000*indexPath.section;
    cell.rowTextField.placeholder = nil;
    cell.rowTextField.text = nil;

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            cell.rowText.text = [self.descriptions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            if ([self.descriptionsPlaceholder[indexPath.row] hasPrefix:@"Placeholder"]) {
                cell.rowTextField.placeholder = [self.descriptionsPlaceholder objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            }else{
                cell.rowTextField.text = [self.descriptionsPlaceholder objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.rowText.text = [self.rooms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            if ([self.contentPlaceholder[indexPath.row] hasPrefix:@"ContentPH"]) {
                cell.rowTextField.placeholder = [self.contentPlaceholder objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            }else{
                cell.rowTextField.text = [self.contentPlaceholder objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}


-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField.tag >= 1000 && ![textField.text isEqualToString: @""]) {
        [self.contentPlaceholder replaceObjectAtIndex:textField.tag - 1000 withObject:textField.text];
    }else if (textField.tag < 1000 && ![textField.text isEqualToString: @""]) {
        [self.descriptionsPlaceholder replaceObjectAtIndex:textField.tag withObject:textField.text];
    }
}


-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @rdelmar, it works great. 
Sorry for my bad explanation BTW.